# Find files with ".logic" in name, but exclude files inside "Project File Backups" subdirectories

Tags: macos, terminal, find

I need to identify all of the files in my directory which have ".logic" in name but exclude files of subdirectories called "Project File Backups".  You can  see an example of one of my projects, which has a series of backup files (file_name.xx.logic).  I only want to see the project file itself, here it is called KillBill.logic.

Here is a project structure for reference

> Audio Files
>
> KillBill.logic
>
> Project File Backups
>
> > KillBill.00.logic
> >
> > KillBill.01.logic
> >
> > KillBill.02.logic
> >
> > KillBill.03.logic
> >
> > KillBill.04.logic
>
> Sampler Instruments
>
> Samples

I have cd'd to the correct directory, and run the following command to show ALL of the files with ".logic" in the name:

```
find . -name "*.logic"
```

I have tried to whittle the results down as per the stated requirement, without success.  My attempts so far have been

- `find . -name "*.logic" -not -path "*Backups*"`
- `find . -name "*.logic"| awk '!*Backups*'` (there's a problem with the awk statement)
- `find . -name "*.logic" ! -name "*Backups*"` ( I suspect that this doesn't work because the name of the file itself doesn't include "Backup" in it

I could `find . -name "*.logic" ! -name "*.*.logic"` to just exclude any .logic file which appears to have version information in its name, but I cannot guarantee that valid files do not have a period in the name, hence my desire to exclude Project File Backups directories.

What invocation of **find** should I use to list the project files and exclude the backup files which exist in each project's "Project File Backups?  I'd prefer to use **find** and not a combination of other commands.

Answer (score 0):

rename all files with .logic in "Project File Backups" into .logicpfb and rename them all back when done

Comment: Thanks, I have found a solution now, posted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do it using only find, but the following worked well

`find . -name "*.logic" | grep -v "Project File Backup" -c`